# Drop down menu not dropping

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am attempting a simple drop down menu using Javascript but when I hover over my link that should display my drop down menu nothing happens. What do you think is wrong with my Javascript?

Javascript:

```
function onHover( divID )
    {
        var div = document.getElementByID( divID );

        if (div)
        {
            div.className = "unHidden";
        }
    }

    function onLeave( divID ) 
    {
        var div = document.getElementByID( divID );

        if (div)
        {
            div.className = "hidden";
        }
    }
```

My css:

```
.hidden { visibility: hidden; }
.unHidden { visibility: visible; z-index: 30; }
```

And finally my HTML:

```
<li>
<a onmouseover="onHover('otherLinks)" onmouseout="onLeave('otherLinks')">Other Links</a>
<div class="hidden" id="otherLinks" onmouseover="onHover('otherLinks)" onmouseout="onLeave('otherLinks')">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="foodNutrition.html">Food & Nutrition</a></li>
    <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</li>
```

Comment: Does it display properly when you do not set the class as "hidden" for the "otherLinks" div tag? I would also try leaving out the onmouseover and onmouseout functions from the "otherLinks" div tag while you troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: Do any of the answers help @Mack?

Answer (score 10):

Is there any reason why you're using Javascript for your drop downs and not HTML and CSS?

*Son of suckerfish drop downs* is a good place to start for a HTML and CSS drop down option: http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/

Answer (score 3):

It is `document.getElementById( divID );`, note that it is "Id" not "ID". You are also missing a single quote, it should be `onmouseover="onHover('otherLinks')"`. I also agree with Dan's answer.

Comment: If you're using Firefox, look into [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) and [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/web-developer/) to help you spot errors.

Answer (score 1):

May be this is the issue:
You have passed the div name like

```
onmouseover="onHover('otherLinks)"
```

Try to give the div name like

```
onmouseover="onHover('otherLinks')"
```

or try [java script ddl](http://javascript-array.com/scripts/simple_drop_down_menu/)

Answer (score 0):

You can only use [css](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp). Or use the library [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).